# UITableView Removing Rows and Sections

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I am receiving an error when trying to remove a row and section from the UITableView.  Here is my scenario:

I have a UITableView with 2 sections.  Each section has one row that I show and hide based on a flag I set in the datasource's model.  Let's say the model changes and I need to add one section and now delete the visible row in another section.  So I use the beginUpdates and endUpdates and include all of the state changes.  Here's a concrete example of what happens if I have the following data:

Old State:

Item A) Section 0 - Rows = 0

Item B) Section 1 - Rows = 1

New State:

Item C) Section 0 - Rows = 0

Item B) Section 1 - Rows = 0

Item A) Section 2 - Rows = 0

So as you can see, I need to reorder the tableview (with animation), add the new section, and hide Section 1 row 1.  I do all of these deltas in a single BeginUpdates/EndUpdates.  I do the sections first, then the rows.  The error I get is the following:

```
NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[NSMutableIndexSet addIndexesInRange:]: Range {2147483647, 1} exceeds maximum index value of NSNotFound - 1'
```

I am able to successfully perform reordering and section additions/removals.  I run into an issue when I try remove a row with a section insert (with reordering).  Here are some logs of the data output once the model has changed and I am trying to calculate the indexpaths and indexsets.

```
2012-02-27 07:33:13.565 XXX[1003:707] Setting new datasource state for cart
2012-02-27 07:33:13.571 XXX[1003:707] Adding section [0] to table
2012-02-27 07:33:13.574 XXX[1003:707] Moving section [0] to section [1]
2012-02-27 07:33:13.578 XXX[1003:707] Moving section [1] to section [2]
2012-02-27 07:33:13.581 XXX[1003:707] Removing indexPath for row [0] in section [0]
```

Here is the actual code that is calculating the updates, reorders, and removals.

```
ShoppingCart *cart = [[SessionState sharedSession] activeCart];

// step 1) build the new array of items to set in current state
NSMutableArray *cartNewLineItemSections = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// sections to remove and add to the current cart's state
NSMutableArray *indexSetsToAdd = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *originalSectionsToMove = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *changedSectionsToMove = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

// used in the loop to determine where the item is at currently if it exists
NSInteger currentOldOrderLineItemSectionIndex = -1;

for (NSInteger currentNewOrderLineItemIndex = 0; currentNewOrderLineItemIndex < [[[cart order] lineItems] count]; 
     ++currentNewOrderLineItemIndex) {
    OrderLineItem *currentNewOrderLineItem = [[[cart order] lineItems] objectAtIndex:currentNewOrderLineItemIndex];

    // currentNewOrderLineItemIndex corresponds to the section number

    // create the new section info
    CartLineItemSectionInfo *cartNewLineItemSection = [[CartLineItemSectionInfo alloc] init];
    [cartNewLineItemSection setOpen:NO]; // defaults to NO
    [cartNewLineItemSection setLineItem:currentNewOrderLineItem];

    [cartNewLineItemSections addObject:cartNewLineItemSection];

    // find the location of the current state
    currentOldOrderLineItemSectionIndex = [cartLineItemSections indexOfObject:cartNewLineItemSection];

    // no longer need the actual section since it has been added
    [cartNewLineItemSection release], cartNewLineItemSection = nil;

    // the new line item exists in old state
    if (currentOldOrderLineItemSectionIndex != NSNotFound) {
        // already in the same spot, do not worry about it
        if (currentOldOrderLineItemSectionIndex == currentNewOrderLineItemIndex) {
            continue;
        }

        [originalSectionsToMove addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:currentOldOrderLineItemSectionIndex]];
        [changedSectionsToMove addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:currentNewOrderLineItemIndex]];

        continue;
    }

    // the new line items are going to be added
    [indexSetsToAdd addObject:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:currentNewOrderLineItemIndex]];
}

// find the deletions (for rows and sections)
NSMutableArray *indexSetsToRemove = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSMutableArray *rowPathsToRemove = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (NSInteger currentOldLineItemSectionIndex = 0; currentOldLineItemSectionIndex < [cartLineItemSections count]; 
     ++currentOldLineItemSectionIndex) {
    CartLineItemSectionInfo *currentOldLineItemSection = [cartLineItemSections objectAtIndex:currentOldLineItemSectionIndex];

    // sections must be deleted separately from the rows
    if (![cartNewLineItemSections containsObject:currentOldLineItemSection]) {
        [indexSetsToRemove addObject:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:currentOldLineItemSectionIndex]];
    }
    else if ([currentOldLineItemSection open]) {
        // change the new one to YES to see what happens?
        CartLineItemSectionInfo *sectionInfo = [cartNewLineItemSections objectAtIndex:[cartNewLineItemSections indexOfObject:currentOldLineItemSection]];
        //[sectionInfo setOpen:YES]; // workaround

        [rowPathsToRemove addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:currentOldLineItemSectionIndex]];
    }
}

// set the old state to the new state so that the UITableView can calculate state correctly
openSectionIndex = NSNotFound;
[cartLineItemSections release], cartLineItemSections = nil;

//NSLog(@"Setting new datasource state for cart");
cartLineItemSections = cartNewLineItemSections;

// animate table updates if there are any
if ([indexSetsToAdd count] > 0 || [indexSetsToRemove count] > 0 || [originalSectionsToMove count] > 0) {
    [self.cartTableView beginUpdates];

    // section additions
    for (NSIndexSet *currentIndexSetToAdd in indexSetsToAdd) {
        //NSLog(@"Adding section [%d] to table", [currentIndexSetToAdd firstIndex]);

        [[self cartTableView] insertSections:currentIndexSetToAdd withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    }

    // section moves
    for (NSInteger currentIndexToMove = 0; currentIndexToMove < [originalSectionsToMove count]; ++currentIndexToMove) {
        NSNumber *oldSection = [originalSectionsToMove objectAtIndex:currentIndexToMove];
        NSNumber *changedSection = [changedSectionsToMove objectAtIndex:currentIndexToMove];

        //NSLog(@"Moving section [%d] to section [%d]", [oldSection intValue], [changedSection intValue]);

        [self.cartTableView moveSection:[oldSection intValue] toSection:[changedSection intValue]];
    }

    // section deletions
    for (NSIndexSet *currentIndexSetToRemove in indexSetsToRemove) {
        [self.cartTableView deleteSections:currentIndexSetToRemove withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    }

    // row deletions
    if ([rowPathsToRemove count] > 0) {
        NSIndexPath *path = [rowPathsToRemove objectAtIndex:0];
        NSLog(@"Removing indexPath for row [%d] in section [%d]", [path row], [path section]);
        [self.cartTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:rowPathsToRemove withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
    }

    [self.cartTableView endUpdates];
}

// release arrays
[indexSetsToAdd release], indexSetsToAdd = nil;
[indexSetsToRemove release], indexSetsToRemove = nil;
[originalSectionsToMove release], originalSectionsToMove = nil;
[changedSectionsToMove release], changedSectionsToMove = nil;
[rowPathsToRemove release], rowPathsToRemove = nil;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the relevant code for removing row/section?

Comment: While reordering? This sounds like you're changing something while enumerating it. We need you to post some code to see what's really going on.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!  I updated the post with code.  Thanks.

Comment: Also, each section will only have one row.  Thanks.